# Jenkins + Sonar project numbers in sonar is nerver reduce

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Hi guys  when I use `Jenkins`+`Maven`+`Sonar`

I found that when I delete a project in sonar and then I run the job in Jenkins 
the total project number in sonar is never reduced . It just repeated increment .
Even I deleted the database and run again the number of project in sonar cant be reduced.

Is there some cache in sonar?
How can I reset the number of project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by a corrupted Elasticsearch index. Shut down your server, delete `$SONARQUBE_HOME/data` and restart.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely, i tried and  it was effective .

Comment: If this solved your problem @Bill.fly, you might [accept] it. :)